# sending emails in bcc to multiple users not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am developing a project in which I am sending emails to multiple user as follows

```
 Dim users(20) As String

        users(0) = "xx@example.com"
        users(1) ="xx@xexample.com"
        users(2) = "xx@example.com"
        users(3) = "xx@example.com"
        users(4) = "xx@example.com"
        users(5) = "xx@example.com"
        users(6) = "xx@example.com"
        users(7) = "xx@example.com"
        users(8) = "xx@example.com"
        users(9) = "xx@example.com"
        users(10) = "xx@example.com"


   For i = 0 To 10
        em.Bcc.Add(users(i))
       or
          em.Bcc.Add(New MailAddress (users(i)))

        Next

        mailClient.Send(em)
```

but it is sending email to only one user I also tried

```
 Dim sendto As String
        sendto = Nothing

        For i = 0 To 10
           sendto = sendto + users(i) + ","
        Next
  em.Bcc.Add(sendto)
```

still not working what is wrong in the code
I am using asp.net and vb.

Comment: Where are you adding the primary recipient?

Comment: @George  I dont know what is primary recipient. I want to send thousands of email in Bcc.

Comment: @George solved it code is workin fine. i was sending to same email address 10 times in bcc but i just found out that u cant send mail multiple time to same email id in Bcc . server will send mail only once.for 10 different email ids it is working :D

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look more like this:

```
Sub SendToMany()
    'create the mail message
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()

    mail.From = New MailAddress("me@mycompany.com", "Ashok P")

    mail.To.Add("you@yourcompany.com")

    mail.Bcc.Add("blindcc1@yourcompany.com")
    mail.Bcc.Add("blindcc2@yourcompany.com")

    'set the content
    mail.Subject = "This is an email"
    mail.Body = "this is the body content of the email."

    'send the message
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient(youmailserver) 'dont forget to include username/password via networkcredentials 
    smtp.Send(mail)
End Sub 'MultipleRecipients
```

Comment: solved it code is workin fine. i was sending to same email address 10 times in bcc but i just found out that u cant send mail multiple time to same email id in Bcc . server will send mail only once.for 10 different email ids it is working :D